# Require is undefined when trying to require mongoose - react

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I'm trying to require mongoose in my project and then i receive this erros:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

help!

code: const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const mongoose= require('mongoose');

im using react

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use mongoose directly in a react app.

You can try the following though:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```